# OWIN token gets invalid after a couple of minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, oauth, owin

I build a MVC backend für a mobile app solutions. The authentication is realized with OWIN and OAuth 2.0. After authenticating the token, pulled from my server, works fine. But after a couple of minutes inactivity in my app, every call is answered with "401, Unauthorized".

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app){            
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
    };

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

My understanding is, that the token should expire after 14 days and not after a few minutes.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you inject bearer token for every call to web api?

Comment: Yes, I am sending it with every call.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which host are you using? IIS? If yes, this might be related to a data protector issue. Make sure to configure static machine keys in web.config.

Comment: Hi Pinpoint! I added a machine key to my web.config and it works like a charm. Thank you! But strange, I don't use a server infrastructure.

Comment: @user1705545 did you find out why setting the static machine key in the web.config worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IIS-Server is not part of a webfarm, but for some reasons it was necessary to generate machineKeys and add them to web.config. After that, issues was gone.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/05/13/iis-7-tip-10-you-can-generate-machine-keys-from-the-iis-manager/